# How to conditionally show fields based on value

Tags: case, filemaker

I'm trying to use a calculation field to conditionally display one of two other fields based on whether or not each one has a value.  Only one of the fields I'm looking at can actually have a value.  So if field one has value, write field one.  If field two has a value write field two.  If neither fields have a value, write nothing.

My calculated statement is written as follows.

```
   Case (
        FieldOne != ""; FieldOne;
        FieldTwo != ""; FieldTwo;
        "")
```

In instances where neither field one or two have a value, nothing is written which is the expected behavior.  However, if either field one or two have a value(a DATE) I'm getting some numeric value displayed.  Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I found my problem was I needed to change the option "Calculation Result is" to a Date.  It was set to a number.

Answer (score 0):

If you're positive that only one field can have a value, then you don't need the Case statement, btw.

```
FieldOne & FieldTwo
```